# no me graba datos en mysql

Tags: php

antes de escribir esta pregunta he revuelto a san google para encontrar una respuesta y las que hay no se asemejan, o por lo menos eso creo, a lo que me ocurre. Tengo el siguiente archivo encontrado en la prehistoria, cuando estudiaba php y lo he rescatado del baul de los recuerdos con pequeñas modificaciones de variables, el caso es que no me da error ninguno en vista previa pero no me graba los datos en la base de datos mysql y no encuentro razon alguna para ello. Necesito encarecidamente ayuda, pues es un proyecto que debia de haber acabado hace dos meses. Gracias a todos y todas.

```
<?php
 $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
                 $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
                 $email=$_POST['email'];
                 $direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
                 $poblacion=$_POST['poblacion'];
                 $provincia=$_POST['provincia'];
                 $cp=$_POST['cp'];
                 $movil=$_POST['movil'];
                 $adultos=$_POST['adultos'];
                 $infantiles=$_POST['infantiles'];
                 $fechareserva=$_POST['fechareserva'];
                 $horareserva=$_POST['horareserva'];
                 $alergias=$_POST['alergias']; 

// Recibimos por POST los datos procedentes del formulario 

                 $nombre= htmlentities($_POST['nombre']);
                 $apellidos= htmlentities($_POST['apellidos']);
                 $email= htmlentities($_POST['email']);
                 $direccion= htmlentities($_POST['direccion']);
                 $poblacion= htmlentities($_POST['poblacion']);
                 $provincia= htmlentities($_POST['provincia']);
                 $cp= htmlentities($_POST['cp']);
                 $movil= htmlentities($_POST['movil']);
                 $adultos= htmlentities($_POST['adultos']);
                 $infantiles= htmlentities($_POST['infantiles']);
                 $fechareserva= htmlentities($_POST['fechareserva']);
                 $horareserva= htmlentities($_POST['horareserva']);
                 $alergias= htmlentities($_POST['alergias']); 

                  // Procedemos a comprobar que los campos del formulario no estén vacíos

            if(empty($_POST['nombre'])){ // comprobamos que el campo nombre no esté vacío
              echo "No has ingresado tu nombre. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['apellidos'])) { // comprobamos que el campo password no esté vacío
              echo "No has ingresado tus apellidos. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['email'])) { // comprobamos que el campo email no esté vacío
              echo "El email ingresado no es válido. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['direccion'])) { // comprobamos que el campo direccion no esté vacío
              echo "No has ingresado la direccion. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['poblacion'])) { // comprobamos que el campo poblacion no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado la poblacion. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['provincia'])) { // comprobamos que el campo provincia no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado la provincia. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['cp'])) { // comprobamos que el campo cp no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado el codigo postal. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>"; 
            }elseif(empty($_POST['movil'])) { // comprobamos que el campo movil no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado el telefono. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['adultos'])) { // comprobamos que el campo adultos no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado los adultos. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['infantiles'])) { // comprobamos que el campo infantiles no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado los niños. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>"; 
            }elseif(empty($_POST['fechareserva'])) { // comprobamos que el campo fechareserva no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado la fechareserva. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['horareserva'])) { // comprobamos que el campo horareserva no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado la horareserva. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
            }elseif(empty($_POST['alergias'])) { // comprobamos que el campo alergias no este vacio
               echo "No has ingresado las alergias. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>"; 
            }else{
           
                 $nombre= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['nombre']);
                 $apellidos= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['apellidos']);
                 $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
                 $direccion= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['direccion']);
                 $poblacion= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['poblacion']);
                 $provincia= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['provincia']);
                 $cp= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cp']);
                 $movil= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['movil']);
                 $adultos= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['adultos']);
                 $infantiles= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['infantiles']);
                 $fechareserva= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['fechareserva']);
                 $horareserva= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['horareserva']);
                 $alergias= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['alergias']); 

// comprobamos que el usuario ingresado no haya sido registrado antes
              $sql= "SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE nombre='$nombre'";
              $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

              if(isset($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellidos']) && !empty($_POST['apellidos']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['direccion']) && !empty($_POST['direccion']) && isset($_POST['poblacion']) && !empty($_POST['poblacion']) && isset($_POST['provincia']) && !empty($_POST['provincia']) && isset($_POST['cp']) && !empty($_POST['cp']) && isset($_POST['movil']) && !empty($_POST['movil']) && isset($_POST['adultos']) && !empty($_POST['adultos']) && isset($_POST['infantiles']) && !empty($_POST['infantiles']) && isset($_POST['fechareserva']) && !empty($_POST['fechareserva']) && isset($_POST['horareserva']) && !empty($_POST['horareserva']) && isset($_POST['alergias']) && !empty($_POST['alergias'])){
                 
              mysqli_query($link,("INSERT INTO reservas (id, nombre, apellidos, email, direccion, poblacion, provincia, cp, movil, adultos, infantiles, fechareserva, horareserva, alergias, freg) VALUES ('$_POST[nombre]','$_POST[apellidos]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[direccion]','$_POST[poblacion]','$_POST[provincia]','$_POST[cp]','$_POST[movil]','$_POST[adultos]','$_POST[infantiles]','$_POST[fechareserva]','$_POST[horareserva]','$_POST[alergias]',NOW())"));
               echo '<script> alert("Reserva registrada");
          location.href="index.php";                    
          </script>';

              }else{
                  echo '<script> alert ("Ha ocurrido un error y no se registraron los datos.");
                      </script>';
              }
            }


?>
```

Comment: Es más fácil si se lo preguntas directamente a PHP. `mysqli_query` te devuelve `FALSE` en caso de error. Mira el ejemplo titulado "estilo por procedimientos" en el [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Saludos. Data un vistazo https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php puede que `mysqli_query`no sea la instrucción correcta; de igual forma revisa el echo hacia los `<script>` no parece evaluas el resultado de la ejecución de la sentencia; igual revisa en `$result` no estas usándolo; solo lo estas creando e inicializando.

Comment: Te sobran unos paréntesis en la sql de inserción. El segundo parametro debe ser una cadena, y estás introduciendo unos paréntesis. Esos sobran. Luego hay que revisar los errores que te de el mysqli.

Comment: Al parecer lo que te está fallando es el `INSERT`. Deberías controlar los posibles errores. Una forma de hacerlo es verificando el resultado de `mysqli_query`  con algo como `if (mysqli_query( .... )) { //todo OK } else { //error, imprimir para depuración el mensaje de error de la API }` La clave de todo es **depurar** y escribir un código controlado. Por cierto, tu código es demasiado repetitivo, usas la super global `$_POST` hasta en la sopa. Es mejor usar un ternario por ejemplo para asignar cada valor a una variable y luego usar esa variable. Así el código queda más limpio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información